# hang analysis - lock on xls OleDbConnection?

Tags: windbg, crash-dumps

Admins told us that there is some prolem in production. They noticed big jump in memory usage and in requests waiting.

I received one crash dump.  I need help analysing it.
Using Debug Diagnostic Tool I found this:

```
Detected possible blocking or leaked critical section at 0x1e5bd320 owned by thread 141 in dllhst3g.exe__Metastorm Process Engine__PID__7444__Date__10_25_2011__Time_01_19_15PM__686__Manual Dump.dmp

Impact of this lock

11,59% of threads blocked

(Threads 97 137 142 143 144 147 207 208 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230)

The following functions are trying to enter this critical section
ACECORE+20eb

The following module(s) are involved with this critical section
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE12\ACECORE.DLL from Microsoft Corporation
```

From the listed threads only thread 142 is waiting for thread 141. All others are waiting for thread 142.

```
~141
 141  Id: 1d14.1b38 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7fee4000 Unfrozen
  Start: msvcrt!_endthreadex+0x2f (77bcb4bc) 
  Priority: 0  Priority class: 32  Affinity: ff

~141s : Edit: new stacktrace after fixing symbols
kb

2a2efdcc 7c827b89 77e6202c 00000003 2a2efe1c ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
2a2efdd0 77e6202c 00000003 2a2efe1c 00000001 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
2a2efe78 7739bbd1 00000003 2a2efea0 00000000 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x11a
2a2efed4 7739ce36 00000002 2a2eff74 ffffffff user32!RealMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x141
2a2efef0 4a77cb28 00000002 2a2eff74 00000000 user32!MsgWaitForMultipleObjects+0x1f
2a2eff84 77bcb530 33c23fe8 00000000 00000000 comsvcs!CSTAThread::WorkerLoop+0x1f9
2a2effb8 77e6482f 37e3b7e8 00000000 00000000 msvcrt!_endthreadex+0xa3
2a2effec 00000000 77bcb4bc 37e3b7e8 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x34

~142
 142  Id: 1d14.1128 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7feb9000 Unfrozen
  Start: msvcrt!_endthreadex+0x2f (77bcb4bc) 
  Priority: 0  Priority class: 32  Affinity: ff

~142s : Edit: new stacktrace after fixing symbols
kb

31b5aa88 7c827b99 7c83d09c 00006c44 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
31b5aa8c 7c83d09c 00006c44 00000000 00000000 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc
31b5aac8 7c83d0e7 00006c44 00000004 00000000 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+0x1a3
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for ACECORE.DLL
31b5aae8 3c9e20eb 1e5bd320 31b5ab3c 2ae13a61 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0xa8
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ACECORE+0x20eb

!clrstack
Shows call to System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
I found it connects to xls
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\temp\somefile.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"

~97
  97  Id: 1d14.730 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7fee5000 Unfrozen
  Start: mscorwks!CorExitProcess+0x21ef9 (79f756cf) 
  Priority: 0  Priority class: 32  Affinity: ff
```

```
Edit: new stacktrace after fixing symbols
~97s
kb
27e1ca10 7c827b99 77e61d1e 000018e4 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
27e1ca14 77e61d1e 000018e4 00000000 00000000 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc
27e1ca84 77e61c8d 000018e4 ffffffff 00000000 kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0xac
27e1ca98 7769c7ad 000018e4 ffffffff 2386d3a8 kernel32!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
27e1cab4 7778b5cb 24a1c758 2386d3a8 00000000 ole32!GetToSTA+0x7c
27e1cad4 7778c38b 27e1cb9c 27e1cc9c 22d3e674 ole32!CRpcChannelBuffer::SwitchAptAndDispatchCall+0xcb
27e1cbb4 776c0585 22d3e674 27e1ccac 27e1cc9c ole32!CRpcChannelBuffer::SendReceive2+0xd3
27e1cc20 776c051a 22d3e674 27e1ccac 27e1cc9c ole32!CAptRpcChnl::SendReceive+0xab
27e1cc74 77ce347f 22d3e674 27e1ccac 27e1cc9c ole32!CCtxComChnl::SendReceive+0x1a9
27e1cc90 77ce352f 45e02be4 27e1ccd8 0600016e rpcrt4!NdrProxySendReceive+0x43
27e1d080 77ce35a6 776762b8 776794ba 27e1d0b8 rpcrt4!NdrClientCall2+0x206
27e1d0a0 77c65037 00000014 00000004 27e1d0d0 rpcrt4!ObjectStublessClient+0x8b
27e1d0b0 776ad951 45e02be4 00000000 27e1d89c rpcrt4!ObjectStubless+0xf
27e1d0d0 776acb4b 77794960 00000001 00000000 ole32!CProcessActivator::CCICallback+0x6d
27e1d0f0 776acafc 77794960 27e1d6f8 00000000 ole32!CProcessActivator::AttemptActivation+0x2c
27e1d12c 776ada3b 77794960 27e1d6f8 00000000 ole32!CProcessActivator::ActivateByContext+0x4f
27e1d154 776aaf9e 77794960 00000000 27e1d89c ole32!CProcessActivator::CreateInstance+0x49
27e1d194 4a777108 27e1d89c 00000000 27e1d5d8 ole32!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance+0xf7
27e1d210 776aaf9e 443dd8f8 00000000 27e1d89c comsvcs!CSTAPoolActivator::CreateInstance+0x5a9
27e1d250 4a766303 27e1d89c 00000000 27e1d5d8 ole32!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance+0xf7
27e1d2a0 776aaf9e 341d3168 00000000 27e1d89c comsvcs!CStdContextActivator::CreateInstance+0x221
27e1d2e0 77727f8a 27e1d89c 00000000 27e1d5d8 ole32!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance+0xf7
27e1d310 776f5c55 0009a0f8 00000000 27e1d89c ole32!CSurrogateProcessActivator::CreateInstance+0xf7
27e1d344 776aaf9e 7779487c 00000000 27e1d89c ole32!CClientContextActivator::CreateInstance+0xc9
27e1d384 776ab12f 27e1d89c 00000000 27e1d5d8 ole32!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance+0xf7
27e1d68c 776a67ba 361f8c54 00000000 00000015 ole32!ICoCreateInstanceEx+0x3f8
27e1d6c0 7769b9b3 361f8c54 00000000 00000000 ole32!CComActivator::DoCreateInstance+0x6a
27e1ddc8 4a7516d8 45bfeb58 361f8c54 00000000 ole32!CComActivator::StandardCreateInstance+0x7c
27e1de3c 4a751fc6 00000000 361f8c40 00000000 comsvcs!CClassFactoryWrapper::ActivateOnMachine+0xaf
27e1de74 7a078d9b 361f8c40 00000000 79edda70 comsvcs!CClassFactoryWrapper::CreateInstance+0x80
27e1e118 7a07a1e6 361f8c40 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!ComClassFactory::CreateInstanceFromClassFactory+0x102
27e1e174 7a0bf10a 1e772994 00000000 27e1e1b4 mscorwks!ComClassFactory::CreateInstance+0x91
27e1e184 7a0c870b 1e772994 1e772994 79faa672 mscorwks!AllocateComObject_ForManaged+0x1e
27e1e1b4 79e9c82b 1e772994 234b20e8 79faa737 mscorwks!AllocateObject+0x38
27e1e1c0 79faa737 05ff2627 00000001 072336fc mscorwks!MethodTable::Allocate+0x35
27e1e260 792c25c3 1e772994 27e1e278 792c257c mscorwks!CRemotingServices::AllocateUninitializedObject+0xdf
27e1e278 792c1951 0f5b1b50 27e1e2d0 03100120 mscorlib_ni+0x2025c3
27e1e290 792c143e 44194464 00000000 00000016 mscorlib_ni+0x201951
27e1e2ac 79e71e04 00000001 27e1e334 79faa569 mscorlib_ni+0x20143e
27e1e2b8 79faa569 792c1400 072336fc 00000000 mscorwks!CTPMethodTable__CallTargetHelper3+0xf
27e1e334 79faa5d8 072336fc 00000000 00000001 mscorwks!CTPMethodTable::CallTarget+0xdd
27e1e348 79faa614 790fd65c 072336fc 00000000 mscorwks!CTPMethodTable::CallTarget+0x14
27e1e368 7a04b578 1e772994 00000000 00000001 mscorwks!CRemotingServices::CreateProxyOrObject+0x38
27e1e414 1e923c99 0f5b1a58 0f5b1b1c 27e1e464 mscorwks!JIT_NewCrossContextHelper+0xa9
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
27e1e430 776e2fae 00000000 00000064 00000001 0x1e923c99
27e1e464 79e71b4c 27e1ef70 00000064 00000001 ole32!CoGetContextToken+0x29
27e1e494 79e821b9 27e1ee70 00000008 27e1ee20 mscorwks!CallDescrWorker+0x33
27e1e514 7a0f851b 27e1ee70 00000008 27e1ee20 mscorwks!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xa3
27e1e5e4 79270454 00000001 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!CMessage::Dispatch+0x162
27e1e63c 7977c16e 00000001 00000000 075d788c mscorlib_ni+0x1b0454
27e1e658 6744d146 0752309c 0f5b19d8 0752304c mscorlib_ni+0x6bc16e
27e1e690 197cb7c7 0d0e3640 79e7a6b8 27e1ea80 System_EnterpriseServices_ni+0x5d146
27e1e70c 197f3d04 27e1eae4 0071f13b 36c6b460 System_EnterpriseServices_Wrapper!__dyn_tls_init_callback  (System_EnterpriseServices_Wrapper+0x2b7c7)
27e1e74c 77720df0 27e1eae4 35ccbed0 00000000 System_EnterpriseServices_Wrapper_197f0000!System::EnterpriseServices::Thunk::FilteringCallbackFunction+0x44
27e1e798 7772189c 00000000 35ccbed0 197f3cc0 ole32!EnterForCallback+0xc4
27e1e8f8 776f0418 27e1e7d0 197f3cc0 27e1eae4 ole32!SwitchForCallback+0x1a3
27e1e924 7769c194 35ccbed0 197f3cc0 27e1eae4 ole32!PerformCallback+0x54
27e1e9bc 776e316c 36c6b460 197f3cc0 27e1eae4 ole32!CObjectContext::InternalContextCallback+0x159
27e1ea0c 79e71d8b 36c6b470 197f3cc0 27e1eae4 ole32!CObjectContext::ContextCallback+0x85
27e1ea68 197cbc82 776e30e7 0f5b1a28 072323f0 mscorwks!PInvokeCalliReturnFromCall
27e1ea88 197cbc82 0010c8f0 00000000 00000008 System_EnterpriseServices_Wrapper!__dyn_tls_init_callback  (System_EnterpriseServices_Wrapper+0x2bc82)
27e1eab4 197cbb51 07231a74 27e1eb2c 79282f85 System_EnterpriseServices_Wrapper!__dyn_tls_init_callback  (System_EnterpriseServices_Wrapper+0x2bc82)
27e1eac0 79282f85 27e1eb44 00000000 00000000 System_EnterpriseServices_Wrapper!__dyn_tls_init_callback  (System_EnterpriseServices_Wrapper+0x2bb51)
27e1eb2c 797f5a0d 03100788 072323f0 075d7830 mscorlib_ni+0x1c2f85
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 mscorlib_ni+0x735a0d
```

And all other threads waiting for thread 142 have same stack trace.

I don't know what thread 141 is doing. Thread 142 cannot open connection to xls file. And not sure why other threads wait for thread 142.

Maybe you have any ideas?

EDIT:

    `analyze -v -hang
GetPageUrlData failed, server returned HTTP status 404
URL requested: http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/dllhst3g_exe/5_2_3790_3959/unknown/0_0_0_0/00000000.htm?Retriage=1`

FAULTING_IP: 
+1e02faf0157df58
00000000 ??              ???

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 00000000
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

FAULTING_THREAD:  0000008d

BUGCHECK_STR:  HANG

PROCESS_NAME:  dllhst3g.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xcfffffff -

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xcfffffff -

MOD_LIST:

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

MANAGED_STACK: !dumpstack -EE
OS Thread Id: 0xc2c (17)
Current frame: 
ChildEBP RetAddr  Caller,Callee
1974f450 655f1110 (MethodDesc 0x651b7efc +0x30 System.Data.ProviderBase.WrappedIUnknown.ReleaseHandle())
1974f93c 792e5e4f (MethodDesc 0x79107064 +0xf System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose(Boolean))
1974f944 792e5d6b (MethodDesc 0x79107030 +0x1b System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Finalize())

DERIVED_WAIT_CHAIN:

Dl Eid Cid     WaitType

---

0   1d14.71c Speculated (Triage)    -->
   17  1d14.c2c Critical Section       -->
   141 1d14.1b38 Event

WAIT_CHAIN_COMMAND:  ~0s;k;;~17s;k;;~141s;k;;

BLOCKING_THREAD:  00001b38

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_HANG_WRONG_SYMBOLS

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  APPLICATION_HANG_WRONG_SYMBOLS

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 7c827b89 to 7c82847c

STACK_TEXT:
2a2efdcc 7c827b89 77e6202c 00000003 2a2efe1c ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
2a2efdd0 77e6202c 00000003 2a2efe1c 00000001 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
2a2efe78 7739bbd1 00000003 2a2efea0 00000000 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x11a
2a2efed4 7739ce36 00000002 2a2eff74 ffffffff user32!RealMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x141
2a2efef0 4a77cb28 00000002 2a2eff74 00000000 user32!MsgWaitForMultipleObjects+0x1f
2a2eff84 77bcb530 33c23fe8 00000000 00000000 comsvcs!CSTAThread::WorkerLoop+0x1f9
2a2effb8 77e6482f 37e3b7e8 00000000 00000000 msvcrt!_endthreadex+0xa3
2a2effec 00000000 77bcb4bc 37e3b7e8 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x34

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet+0
7c82847c c3              ret

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet+0

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: ntdll

IMAGE_NAME:  ntdll.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4cc18322

STACK_COMMAND:  ~141s ; kb

BUCKET_ID:  HANG_ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet+0

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_HANG_WRONG_SYMBOLS_cfffffff_ntdll.dll!KiFastSystemCallRet

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/dllhst3g_exe/5_2_3790_3959/45d69678/unknown/0_0_0_0/bbbbbbb4/cfffffff/00000000.htm?Retriage=1

### Followup: MachineOwner

Not sure I understand it. But thread 17 is finalizer thread. So looks like it is blocked? And I thinkg it as again some kind of access to xls?

`` ~17s

    kb
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child

1974f08c 7c827b99 7c83d09c 00003a98 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
1974f090 7c83d09c 00003a98 00000000 00000000 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc
1974f0cc 7c83d0e7 00003a98 00000004 00000001 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+0x1a3
1974f0ec 2ae1fa94 29202124 32787727 00000000 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0xa8
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
1974f160 4c856487 2263eff4 00000000 00000005 ACEOLEDB!DllGetClassObject+0xdc2d
1974f174 4c862d06 2263eff4 4c8633c4 2263efe8 oledb32!CACMDynamic::CmFinalRelease+0x50
1974f17c 4c8633c4 2263efe8 2263efe8 1974f1e4 oledb32!CDCM::FinalRelease+0x1b
1974f198 4c8633f6 00000000 2263efe8 1974f1b8 oledb32!ATL::CComPolyObject::~CComPolyObject+0x2a
1974f1a8 4c88d5ad 2263efe8 2370a39c 1974f1f4 oledb32!ATL::CComPolyObject::Release+0x25
1974f1b8 4a757681 1a271fa0 2263efe8 2370a39c oledb32!CDCMCreator::DestroyResource+0xf
1974f1f4 4a75793e 2370a39c 2263efe8 00000000 comsvcs!CHolder::SafeDispenserDriver::DestroyResource+0x20
1974f20c 4a758a35 23151cd0 00000000 2fa44808 comsvcs!CHolder::ProcessDestroyList+0x2e
1974f238 4c88d30e 23151cd0 2263efe8 2263efe8 comsvcs!CHolder::FreeResource+0x7f
1974f268 4c878a3a 2263efe8 00000000 271aa824 oledb32!CDCMCreator::ReleaseResource+0x31
1974f288 4c8545e7 271aa824 00000000 4c85456a oledb32!CDPO::ReturnDCMToPool+0x89
1974f294 4c85456a 271aa818 271aa818 1974f320 oledb32!CDPO::FinalRelease+0xb
1974f2b0 4c88e78a 271aa818 1974f2d0 4c85218c oledb32!ATL::CComPolyObject::~CComPolyObject+0x2a
1974f2bc 4c85218c 00000001 00000000 000eaaf8 oledb32!ATL::CComPolyObject::`scalar deleting destructor'+0xd
1974f2d0 4c8521aa 271aa818 1974f330 79f63ff9 oledb32!ATL::CComPolyObject::Release+0x27
1974f2dc 79f63ff9 271aa824 3b6a3777 000eaaf8 oledb32!ATL::CComContainedObject::Release+0x11
1974f330 79f640ac 271aa828 3b6a3733 000eaaf8 mscorwks!ReleaseTransitionHelper+0x5f
1974f374 79f64110 271aa828 00000000 3b6a37ef mscorwks!SafeReleaseHelper+0x8c
1974f3a8 79f53b5d 271aa828 00000000 3b6a3017 mscorwks!SafeRelease+0x2f
1974f450 655f1110 000eaaf8 00000000 1974f470 mscorwks!MarshalNative::Release+0xb0
1974f460 79e71b4c 1974f4dc 000c5958 1974f4f0 System_Data_ni!_bidW103  (System_Data_ni+0x4a1110)
1974f470 79e821b9 1974f540 00000000 1974f510 mscorwks!CallDescrWorker+0x33
1974f4f0 79e96531 1974f540 00000000 1974f510 mscorwks!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xa3
1974f634 79e96564 655f10e0 1974f6bc 1974f6a4 mscorwks!MethodDesc::CallDescr+0x19c
1974f650 79e96c4c 655f10e0 1974f6bc 1974f6a4 mscorwks!MethodDesc::CallTargetWorker+0x1f
1974f670 79eccd2a 1974f6a4 0b402780 00000004 mscorwks!MethodDescCallSite::Call_RetObjPtr+0x1c
1974f770 79eccd5e 0b402780 000eaaf8 000eaaf8 mscorwks!SafeHandle::RunReleaseMethod+0x89
1974f870 79eccbf4 00000001 0d0e3640 79e7a1c8 mscorwks!SafeHandle::Release+0x11b
1974f89c 79f83999 3b6a3d7b 00000000 000eaaf8 mscorwks!SafeHandle::Dispose+0x23
1974f93c 792e5e4f 1974f970 792e5d6b 0b3ac100 mscorwks!SafeHandle::Finalize+0xab
1974f944 792e5d6b 0b3ac100 ffffffff 00000000 mscorlib_ni+0x225e4f
1974f970 79f7169a 1974f9c4 79ef465c 1974fc1c mscorlib_ni+0x225d6b
1974f9d4 79f7175b 0b402780 792e5d50 08000000 mscorwks!MethodTable::GetObjCreateDelegate+0xaf
1974f9f4 79f71609 0b402780 0b402780 00000000 mscorwks!MethodTable::CallFinalizer+0xa0
1974fa08 79fd46a6 0b402780 3b6a3e1f 00000000 mscorwks!SVR::CallFinalizer+0xa6
1974fa58 79fd45d7 000eaaf8 00000415 1974fadf mscorwks!SVR::GCHeap::TraceGCSegments+0x1b0
1974fae0 79f5832f 0740eeb4 00000000 1974feb0 mscorwks!SVR::GCHeap::TraceGCSegments+0x2f6
1974faf4 79e9848f 1974fd04 000eaaf8 00000000 mscorwks!SVR::ProfScanRootsHelper+0x69
1974fb08 79e9842b 1974feb0 1974fb90 79fa6a6b mscorwks!Thread::DoADCallBack+0x32a
1974fb9c 79e98351 1974feb0 3b6a3f9f 000eaaf8 mscorwks!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0xe3
1974fbd8 79ec4322 1974feb0 00000000 1974fc98 mscorwks!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0x30a
1974fbe8 79f581f3 1974feb0 1974fc8c 79fa6a6b mscorwks!Thread::RaiseCrossContextException+0x434
1974fc98 79f58279 1a9cb678 79ec430e 1974feb0 mscorwks!Thread::DoADCallBack+0xcd
1974fcb8 79f58265 1974feb0 1974fd20 79f582e4 mscorwks!Thread::DoADCallBack+0x322
1974fcc4 79f582e4 1a9cb678 79f58316 1974fd04 mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase::FinalizerAppDomain+0x25
1974fd20 79fd45d7 000eaaf8 00000000 1974fda7 mscorwks!SVR::GCHeap::TraceGCSegments+0x251
1974fda8 79fd48a8 00000000 00000000 1974feb0 mscorwks!SVR::GCHeap::TraceGCSegments+0x2f6
1974fdc0 79e9848f 1974feb0 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!SVR::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadWorker+0xb7
1974fdd4 79e9842b 1974feb0 1974fe5c 79fa6a6b mscorwks!Thread::DoADCallBack+0x32a
1974fe68 79e98351 1974feb0 3b6a3ae3 00000000 mscorwks!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0xe3
1974fea4 79f074d4 1974feb0 00000000 1a9cb678 mscorwks!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0x30a
1974fecc 79f074e5 79fd4809 00000008 1974ff14 mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase_NoADTransition+0x32
1974fedc 79f090b3 79fd4809 3b6a3b53 00000000 mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase::FinalizerBase+0xd
1974ff14 79f75715 00000000 00000007 ffffffff mscorwks!SVR::GCHeap::FinalizerThreadStart+0xbb
1974ffb8 77e6482f 000eb528 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x49
1974ffec 00000000 79f756cf 000eb528 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x34 ``

Comment: I would try db 77bcb4bc to see what file GetModuleHandleA was trying to open. That might give you some clues.

Comment: Thanks. I added output from db.

Comment: Thread 141 is some sort of COM thread. However it is hard to tell what it is doing without symbols. Can you try fixing up symbols for comsvcs.dll? Fixing all other symbols wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: How do I recognize that there are no symbols? I thought that if I see stacktrace with function names it is ok. I thought I had symbols set up correctly. I debug on XP applications from win 2003. I downloaded symbol files from microsoft.

Comment: Ok I think i fixed symbols using .sympath SRV*d:\websymbols*d:\websymbols\win2003*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols - added microsoft server to this list. Look at another kb from thread 141.

Comment: I edited my post and entered new stacktraces for all the threads after fixing symbols.

Comment: Unless you are so familiar with dump analysis (which is not as you don't even use !CLRStack or !threads or !threadpool or psscor2). In this case, you should open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and share the dump with Microsoft support guys.

Comment: I use all of those. How did you come up with this!? Those are not relevant here. And to open a case with support you have to pay and wait weeks. Good luck when you need to fix it now. And for your information the bug was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find who owns the following critical section that your thread is waiting on:

```
1974f0ec 2ae1fa94 29202124 32787727 00000000 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0xa8
```

You can do an automated critical section analysis with call stacks:

```
!locks -v
```

This will dump all critical section locks that are in a locked state and the call stacks of the threads, you then need to scan each call stack for each lock to see if say Thread A is waiting on lock 1 which is owned by Thread B, Thread B is waiting on lock 2 which is owned by Thread A.

Hope this helps